# Access current record in admin on rest edit

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, admin-on-rest

I need to access the current record in admin on rest Edit. I have an entity and need one of it's properties to do a conditional task. I searched all over the internet and found nothing.

```js
export const UserEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextField source="Username" label="Username" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible with `admin-on-rest` but this is where React comes to the rescue, you can create a component to add this behaviour.

Something like:

```
const WithProps = ({children,...props}) => children(props);
```

And use it like this:

```
export const UserEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <WithProps>{({record,...props})=>
          <SimpleForm record={record} {...props}>
            <TextField source="Username" label="Username" />
          </SimpleForm>}
        </WithProps>
    </Edit>
);
```

Comment: Thanks Dennie for your answer. But my problem is I don't have access to record. How do I pass it to WithProps?

Comment: You don't.Admin-on-rest will clone the `WithProps` component and add the `record` prop to it. So this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `aor-dependent-input`?

https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input

It allows to display an input depending on other inputs values. It's authored and supported by the admin-on-rest core team.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you don't have an access to a record inside a SimpleForm.

Perhaps, you can define a custom field and wrap a TextField inside it with access to the record so as to perform a conditional check as desired.

ex:

```
const CustomTextField = ({record = {}, source}) => (
  { record.foo ? <TextField source="username" label="username" /> : <WhateverField /> }
);
```

and then, use the CustomTextField in your UserEdit instead.